# Interpretation of coefficients of a Probit model

Tags: regression, econometrics, default-probability

The exact problem I am trying to solve is as follows. I have a Probit specification:

$$ P_t = \Phi(\beta^T x_t) $$

where $\Phi$ is a standard normal CDF and $x$ is a matrix of independent variables measured at time $t$. $P$ is the probability of success.

I am trying to calculate the marginal effect of change in each $x$ over the probability. Formally:

I have two estimates estimated at different time points:
$$ P_t = \Phi(\beta^T x_t) \quad ... (1)$$ and
$$ P_{t+1} = \Phi(\beta^T x_{t+1}) \quad ... (2)$$

I want to get the weighted impact of each change in $x$ that is $\Delta x = x_{t+1}-x_t$ over the difference in the probability of success $\Delta P = P_{t+1} - P_t$. In simple linear regression, this is easy as the marginal impact was the coefficient multiplied by the absolute change in the variable.

I have already tried to calculate the marginal probability effect:

$$\frac {\partial P_t} {\partial x_{it}} = \beta_i \phi(\beta^T x_t)$$

and then take a simple difference:
$$\frac {\partial P_{t+1}} {\partial x_{i \ t+1}} x_{t+1}- \frac {\partial P_t} {\partial x_{it}} x_t$$
where $\phi$ is the standard normal PDF. However, the problem with this approach is that the marginal effect is a function of every independent variable. Suppose, $x_{it} = x_{i \ t+1}$ then the marginal impact would be non-zero if any other $x_j$ changed. This should intuitively be zero as the driver did not change at all.

Any insights or sources would be much appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Is this really about quantitative finance? The question may be better suited for Cross Validated or Economics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Perhaps this could be used in quantitative finance, but it really looks like a pure statistics question, one where I am interested in the answer and would like to see one on [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You have done a good analysis that tells you all you need to know. Just note that the marginal effect should keep all of the other regressors constant (ensure that *ceteris* is actually *paribus*). Otherwise, what you get from
$$
\frac {\partial P_{t+1}} {\partial x_{i \ t+1}} x_{t+1}- \frac {\partial P_t} {\partial x_{it}} x_t
$$
is not a marginal effect of $x_{i}$.